# Time complexity of squaring and sorting an array

Tags: java, algorithm

I have this code that returns the square of an array in sorted order and I'm trying to determine its time complexity. I do one loop through the data (`O(n)`), and then use merge sort (`O(n log n)`). I take this to mean that I'm doing `n * n log n` work, so it's `n^2` complexity. But when I checked an answer for this question, the time complexity for this function is apparently just `n log n`. Why is that?

```
public int[] sortedSquares(int[] A) {
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        A[i] = A[i] * A[i];           
    }
    mergeSort(A);
    return A;
}
```

Comment: `O(n) + (O(n) = O(2n) = O(n)`. Now, you still have the `log n` factor, but the same principle applies.

Comment: Its like your for loop takes **O(n)** and mergeSort takes **O(nLogn)** and since merge sort is not inside the loop it will work only once. So the resulting time complexity will be **O(n) + O(nLogn)** i.e. **O(nLogn)** . Hope this helps you out .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One loop take you `O(n)` and THEN you do the mergeSort `(O(n log n))`

So your total time complexity will be `O(n) + (O(n log n))` but we only need to concern the bigger value so your time complexity will be `(O(n log n))`

IF you are doing like this:

```
public int[] sortedSquares(int[] A) {
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        A[i] = A[i] * A[i];  
        mergeSort(A);
    }

     return A;
}
```

Your time complexity in this is will be `O(n * n * log(n))`

Answer (score 2):

Your first for loop is taking `O(n)` time complexity and merge sort is taking `O(nlogn)`

so, overall your time complexity will be `T(n) = O(n) + O(nlogn)`

As we exclude the lower boundries while calculating time complexity, so your overall time complexity will be `O(nlogn)`

Answer (score 1):

```
public int[] sortedSquares(int[] A) {
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        A[i] = A[i] * A[i];           
    }
    mergeSort(A);
    return A;
}
```

Time Complexity: O(N) + O(N log N) = O(N log N)
Explanation:
Firstly you have traversed the array so it takes O(N) time. After the traversing the array you have applied merge sort which takes O(N log N). But we have considered the higher complexity so your time complexity is **O(N log N).**